# Getting a storm of "error TS5055" messages on every TypeScript Compile in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to convert a JavaScript based express project to TypeScript using VS Code 1.6.1. I can now add new files in TypeScript and compile them to JavaScript. However, every time I compile a TypeScript file, I get a long list of errors - one per existing (legacy) JavaScript file - saying:

> error TS5055: cannot write file XYZ.js because it would overwrite input file

How do I stop this?

My tsconfig looks like this:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This problem occurred because the TypeScript compiler tries to transpile everything, including files that are already JavaScript, in which case it understandably complains that it will overwrite its input. I found no combination of "include" and "exclude" statements which could stop this behaviour.

The solution is to add a new field, "outDir",  to the compilerOptions, so it looks like this

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "generated"
    }
}
```

This will cause tsc to copy ALL ts and js in your project to the specified folder. There will be no more of those pesky TS5055 errors.

If the import references in your project are all relative, this should be fine. Otherwise, for example, if your Node.js project is using a "public" folder at the top level, you might have to modify path references in your code accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

The error is happening also when the `d.ts` are generated `tsc` take all files it found in the output directory and sub-directories by default.

Assuming your output is in the `out` directory, you have to exclude it in the tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  // All the options you want...

  // Redirect output structure to the directory
  "outDir": "out"

  // Exclude here the directories you want ts do not compile...
  "exclude": [
    "out"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `exclude` has been since moved to the root level, I tested on TS v4.4.4

Answer (score 7):

Changing `allowJs` in tsconfig.json from `true` to `false` will tell the typescript compiler to not transpile javascript files. That should fix the problem.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options

Comment: This is exactly what we want here

Comment: Can confirm it works. Pretty whack that in order to import JS files we have to set `allowJs` to `false` 

Answer (score 4):

My problem was a bit different - adding a new `typescript` file to an existing configuration.
Turns out there was a problem with an import inside it that caused a cycle and that's why the compilation failed in my case.

Comment: I had something similar. A had `"files": ["index.ts"]` and added `"index.test.ts"`. index.test.ts contained `import { ... } from '.'` and I changed this to `import { ... } from './index'` to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to compile, but only check errors, you can use: `"noEmit": true`